# Как добавить одну таблицу в другую в PostgrSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Плотно занялся изучением `SQL` совсем недавно. Самые базовые запросы типа `SELECT`, `INSERT INTO`, `CREATE` и т.д. мне знакомы. Но столкнулся с задачей, где мне необходимо одну таблицу поместить в другую(сделать колонкой другой). Например: есть у меня таблица с `Dish`(`id`, `name`, `dish_cost`, `about_dish`) и есть таблица `Order`(`id`, `address`, `phone_number` и тут же мне нужно чтобы было `dish`(и здесь внутри колонки находилась таблица `Dish`)). Как можно это сделать? Пользуюсь БД `PostgreSQL`;

Comment: Таблицы в колонки не поместить. Но можно поместить ID блюд в заказ. Либо в виде массива, через запятую, либо, что лучше с точки зрения приведения к нормальной форме - сделать отдельную таблицу для связи блюд с заказами в виде многие-ко-многим. В ней будет ID заказа и ID блюда. В итоге вы будете собирать эти данные по ID заказа и блюда из 3 таблиц.

Comment: Я думаю многие ко многим лучший вариант?

Comment: Да, это будет гораздо лучше массива ID - проще удалять/добавлять блюда, не надо массив вручную править.

Comment: оформите как ответ вопроса, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблицы в колонки не поместить.

Но можно поместить ID блюд в заказ. Либо в виде массива, через запятую, либо, что лучше с точки зрения приведения к нормальной форме - сделать отдельную таблицу для связи блюд с заказами в виде многие-ко-многим. В ней будет ID заказа и ID блюда. В итоге вы будете собирать эти данные по ID заказа и блюда из 3 таблиц. Это будет гораздо лучше массива ID - проще удалять/добавлять блюда, не надо массив вручную править.

Comment: А вы уверены что связь многие ко многим? почему не многие к одному?

Comment: В заказе может быть много блюд. А одно блюдо может быть в нескольких заказах

Comment: хорошо. спасибо!